# Django-cms Aldryn news and blog app templates arent working accordingly

Tags: django, django-cms

im setting up the aldryn news and blog application in Django-cms. When I do pip install aldryn-newsblog everything works fine but I cant find or edit the templates to style the front end. If I try to install it manually or clone it via GitHub, the templates dont work accordingly.

This is on Django-cms 3.6 and alryn 2.2, Ive tried to install it via pip and also clone it via GitHub. By pip app works fine but I dont know how to edit the templates. and by cloning only one templates is rendered for list view, detailed view, categories, search or tags.

Am i missing some kind of setting when i clone the project, as it works fine when i pip install it??

Comment: Where are you cloning it from?

Comment: copy the templates folder of the news-blog and paste in your templates folder.

Comment: Thanks @Maruthesh for that suggestion. That solved the same problem that I had with aldryn_search.